# Highslide images only loads

Tags: highslide

Here is the problem i have the product page:

http://www.ignitionmarketing.co.za/beta/product_info.php?ID=3165

On the product image i have included High Slide. But if clicked on the image it only loads no popup or anything appears. The images are generated from a database and link to the same image is that what may be causing the problem?

All the files are there as i have checked and the code was included in the footer for loading speeds!

Please any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use highslide-full.min.js instead of highslide.js. Trust me on this one. ;)

I think the problem is simply that Highslide doesn't know where its graphics directory is. In your head section, just *after* you load the HS script, try adding this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
hs.graphicsDir="css/highslide/graphics/"
</script>
```

Comment: Yes directory issues =D Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad that fixed it! It's probably the single most common problem when someone gets the dreaded endless "Loading...."